# Compare two txt files with awk, both have 4 columns present in it

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sh, ksh

I have two txt files let's say file1 and file2 with 4 columns.....
Table name,column name,data type,length

File1 contains

```
Emp name varchar 30
Emp ID   int 20
Emp age  int 3
Emp no   int 10
```

File2 contains

```
Emp name varchar 30
Emp ID   varchar 20
Emp age  int 5
Emp DOB. Date 10
```

I want to compare file1 with file2 based on column 1 and column 2 (table name, column name)

Based on that 2 columns compare if there is any mismatch in data type and length columns

If there is a mismatch in data type or length
Display the corresponding row like (data from both files, same row)

```
Emp age  int 3 Emp age  int 5
```

Output the unique rows in file 1 like

```
Emp emailid varchar 50
```

As output of another command

When I use comm command for unique records of file 1
It gives output like

```
Emp ID   int 20
Emp age  int 3
Emp no   int 10
```

But want the o/p to be only

```
Emp no int 10
```

Because columns (table name,column names) are present in file 2 also.

Comment: pls add desired output for your current file1 and file2 input files.

Comment: and whatever code you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

based on your long description, I come up with this one-liner:

```
awk '{k=$1FS$2}NR==FNR{a[k]=$3FS$4;next}
   k in a{if($3FS$4!=a[k])print $0,k,a[k];next}7' file2 file1
```

With your given input files:

```
kent$  head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
Emp name varchar 30
Emp ID   int 20
Emp age  int 3
Emp no   int 10

==> f2 <==
Emp name varchar 30
Emp ID   varchar 20
Emp age  int 5
Emp DOB. Date 10

kent$  awk '{k=$1FS$2}NR==FNR{a[k]=$3FS$4;next}k in a{if($3FS$4!=a[k])print $0,k,a[k];next}7' f2 f1
Emp ID   int 20 Emp ID varchar 20
Emp age  int 3 Emp age int 5
Emp no   int 10
```

Note that all case-sensitive. E.g. `id` and `ID` are different.

Comment: Hi Kent....thanks for the quick reply. One small change I do not want the row Emp no int 10 in the output for this query....I want that result in another query(unique in file1)

Comment: @cvinay24 it is easy,  just remove the `7` at the end

Comment: Kent,contents of file 2 are not being displayed by the awk command......o/p when the command is executed: emp ID int 20.....desired o/p: emp ID int 20 emp ID varchar 20

Comment: @cvinay24 I don't know what do you want in output now.... check my comment under your question...